# ng-repeat - not updating the view when the array is changed in controller, using controller as syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following function inside controller:

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function(myServ, $scope){
  var ctrlScope = this;
  ctrlScope.myData = [];

  function getData(){
    myServ.getData().then(function(data){
      $scope.$evalAsync(function(){
        ctrlScope.myData = data;
      });
    });
  }

  getData();  // myData is initialised properly

  ctrlScope.update = function(){
    // Data has already changed in backend
    getData();   //myData inside controller is updated but ng-repeat is not able to show on the view the updated array
  };
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div data-ng-controller="myCtrl as mc">
  <span data-ng-repeat="d in mc.myData">{{d.name}}</span>
  <button data-ng-click="mc.update()"> Update </button>
</div>
```

`getData()` initialises `ng-repeat` properly but is not able to update the view even if the controller has updated the data.

Comment: How do you update the data? is it with a 3rd party like jQuery?

Comment: It is is getting updated by some other action , not showing here to keep the question clear.

Comment: <span data-ng-repeat="d in mc.myData">[[d.name]]</span> replace with curly brackets

Comment: I am using "[[]]" as interpolator for angular, because we are using handlebars too which also has "{{}}" interpolator. Sorry for confusion, i will edit anyways

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the reference of the array. That's why the data is not getting updated in the UI. You can update the data as below:

```
function getData(){
    myServe.getData().then(function(data){
        ctrlScope.myData.length = 0;
        ctrlScope.myData.push.apply(ctrlScope.myData, data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Add `$scope().apply()`

```
ctrlScope.update = function(){
        // Data has already changed in backend
        getData();   //myData inside controller is updated but ng-repeat is not able to show on the view the updated array

        $scope().apply();
      };
```

Comment: I forgot to add $scope.$evalAsync in the code, it basically queues up the update in the current digest cycle. $scope.$apply is not required because we are not going out of scope of angular. It is required when we do an update outside angular's scope which is not the scenario here.